# How to discover if a c-string can be encoded to NSString with a given encoding

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

I am trying to implement code that converts `const char *` to `NSString`. I would like to try multiple encodings in a specified order until I find one that works. Unfortunately, all the `initWith...` methods on `NSString` say that the results are undefined if the encoding doesn't work.

In particular, (sometimes) I would like to try first to encode as `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` which never seems to fail. Instead it just encodes gobbledygook. Is there some kind of check I can perform ahead of time? (Like `canBeConvertedToEncoding` but in the other direction?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying encodings one by one until you find a match, consider asking `NSString` to help you out here by using [`+[NSString stringEncodingForData:encodingOptions:convertedString:usedLossyConversion:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413576-stringencodingfordata?language=objc), which, given string data and some options, may be able to detect the encoding for you, and return it (along with the actual decoded string).

Specifically for your use-case, since you have a list of encodings you'd like to try, the `encodingOptions` parameter will allow you to pass those encodings in using the [`NSStringEncodingDetectionSuggestedEncodingsKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstringencodingdetectionsuggestedencodingskey?language=objc).

So, given a C string and some possible encoding options, you might be able to do something like:

```
NSString *decodeCString(const char *source, NSArray<NSNumber *> *encodings) {
    NSData * const cStringData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)source length:strlen(source) freeWhenDone:NO];
    
    NSString *result = nil;
    BOOL usedLossyConversion = NO;
    NSStringEncoding determinedEncoding = [NSString stringEncodingForData:cStringData
                                                          encodingOptions:@{NSStringEncodingDetectionSuggestedEncodingsKey: encodings,
                                                                            NSStringEncodingDetectionUseOnlySuggestedEncodingsKey: @YES}
                                                          convertedString:&result
                                                      usedLossyConversion:&usedLossyConversion];
    
    /* Decide whether to do anything with `usedLossyConversion` and `determinedEncoding. */
    return result;
}
```

Example usage:

```
NSString *result = decodeCString("Hello, world!", @[@(NSShiftJISStringEncoding), @(NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding), @(NSASCIIStringEncoding)]);
NSLog(@"%@", result); // => "Hello, world!"
```

If you don't 100% care about using *only* the list of encodings you want to try, you can drop the `NSStringEncodingDetectionUseOnlySuggestedEncodingsKey` option.

---

One thing to note about the encoding array you pass in: although the documentation doesn't promise that the suggested encodings are attempted in order, spelunking through the disassembly of the (*current*) method implementation shows that the array is enumerated using fast enumeration (i.e., in order). I can imagine that this could change in the future (or have been different in the past) so if this is somehow a hard requirement for you, you could theoretically work around it by repeatedly calling `+stringEncodingForData:encodingOptions:convertedString:usedLossyConversion:` one encoding at a time in order, but this would likely be incredibly expensive given the complexity of this method.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. If I can get it working I'll mark it solved.

Comment: @rpatters1 Note that string encoding detection is _extremely_ difficult and at least slightly probabilistic in nature, so the results may not be perfect, but I hope this works for your use case.

Comment: It's going to work. Something curious, though.  I can encode a cstring in MacOSRoman (without errors), then send it back into this routine and it encodes the NSString perfectly (using MacOSRoman encoding) but sets the usedLossyConversion bool anyway. I was treating this an error, but now I think maybe I shouldn't be. I'm wondering if there is some other error condition I should check other than the returned string being nil.

Comment: @rpatters1 Based on a bit of cursory testing, I _believe_ that's a bug. It looks to me like the result of `usedLossyConversion` is influenced by whether more than one encoding was attempted, even on success. For instance, trying all 256 Mac OS Roman codepoints does _not_ report lossy conversion if I pass in exclusively `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` and set `NSStringEncodingDetectionUseOnlySuggestedEncodingsKey: YES`, but if either of those is not true, it reports lossy conversion, even on success.

Comment: It also appears that one encoding, UTF-7, _always_ reports lossy encoding on success, regardless of options. My suggestion would be to ignore the "lossy" flag and rely on whether `result` is non-`nil` to report a success. Depending on the specifics of your use-case, that _might_ be enough, but if you need to possibly recover some codepoints, you could also try taking `result`, _reconverting_ it back into the target encoding, then walking both strings to see if there's actually a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice. For now I'm staying with checking `result` for `nil`, but if it becomes an issues, walking the string back is a possible solution.

Comment: @rpatters1 Excellent. Best of luck!